# express-validator : How to check for an Array of Email IDs?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator, express-router

Let's say I have a post request with body :

```
{
    "from":"mr.x@example.com",
    "recipient":[
        "john.doe@email.com",
        "ramesh.suresh@example.com",
        "jane.doe"
    ]
}
```

Here is my request handler :

```
const { validationResult, body } = require("express-validator");

router.post(
    "/api/request",
    body("from").notEmpty().isEmail(),
    body("recipient").isArray({ min: 1 }),
    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    }
);
```

How to do validate whether "recipients" is an array of email ids using express validator? Now I know that `isEmail()` checks for email and `isArray()` checks for an Array. How do I combine the 2 to check if it's an "Array of Email Ids"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two checks in the following way, using [wildcards](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/wildcards.html):

```
const { validationResult, body } = require("express-validator");

router.post(
    "/api/request",
    body("from").notEmpty().isEmail(),
    body("recipient").isArray({ min: 1 }),
    body("recipient.*").not().isArray().isEmail(), // Here lies the "magic" :)
    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    }
);
```

NOTE: you need the ".not().isArray()" because a nested array of emails would pass the check